# !$ not automatic in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, kali-linux

Does anybody know how to change the behaviour of !$ in Kali Linux ? Right now, if I reference last argument using !$ I must enter the new command with the last argument instead of executing a new command with the last argument in one shot.

!$ not in one shot

How do I update it to change my wd to ~/Desktop quickly without having to enter the new line cd ../Desktop so it does it automatically ?.

This happens automatically in Parrot OS, for example... So if you can enlighten me to change this I'd be thankful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start by using `ps $$` or `echo $SHELL` to check what shell you're using in both cases – e.g. Bash and Zsh are similar but not identical, and the default behavior of `!` expansions may differ.

In Bash, set/unset the `histverify` option (e.g. through ~/.bashrc):

```
shopt -s histverify

shopt -u histverify
```

Zsh appears to have the same option, although configured differently:

```
unsetopt histverify
```

It could also be that these options were changed as part of the customizations included by each distro, and/or as part of the shell "theme" that's being used (i.e. the same package that provides that fancy prompt style in your screenshot).

Alternative: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (Alt+period) will insert the last argument at cursor position, so you could type `cd [Alt+.][Enter]` in fewer keystrokes than using history expansion.